# Pipe between two text files in BASH

Tags: bash, unix

I'm new to all this(one day old bash coder) so as much as stupid this question might sound, please take your time and respond accordingly :)

I created a script in BASH that should do some things to a given input(which is a text file).
 I'm having some hard time trying to figure out how to use pipeline to run the script(which is called cleanLines, for the sake of the question) on a text file (named test.txt) so that it'll "clean his lines".
I added the below line of code to the top of my script file(cleanLines):

```
PATH=${PATH[*]}:.
```

Now what?

```
./test.txt | ./cleanLines.txt
```

Doesn't seem to work.

I should note that the files are in the same directory, if that worths anything to you.

EDIT: Oh and cleanLines is also a text file(.txt).
And it gives me the error:

```
-bash: ./cleanLines.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: What is the name of your script, and can you show the code?

Comment: 1. Your script should have the extension `.sh` if it's a shell or bash script, 2. Scripts often need to be made executable by running `chmod +x  name_of_script.sh`. Try running it via `/bin/bash name_of_script.sh` after doing these two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe `|` redirects the output of a command, but `test.txt` is not a command. You can read more about redirection [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection) or [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). To redirect input from a file you would do this instead:

```
cleanLines < test.txt
```

This assumes that your script is executable and expecting input from standard input.

Comment: It gives me this error:
-bash: ./cleanLines.txt: Permission denied

Comment: `cleanLines` is not a program, it's another text file.

Comment: Then you'll need to make it executable.  Ensure it has a proper shebang and then `chmod +x cleanLines`. Don't name your script `.txt`, it will just confuse things!

Comment: @totoro OP said "run the script(which is called cleanLines)"

Comment: "Oh and cleanLines is also a text file(.txt)" kinda confused me.

Comment: @LamaEu glad to help. Please vote up any answers you found useful, and mark as accepted the one which best answered your question. This will mark it as closed, and give us both some imaginary internet points!

Comment: @miken32 I laughed my ass off at imaginary internet points HAHA.
Sadly I can't upvote just yet

Comment: @totoro I know, I made the same mistake at first, so added the advice to my comment

Comment: @miken32 By the way, just trying my luck here.

Comment: @miken32 I'm having this issue, when I try to run cleanLines and do: cleanLines < test.txt > output.txt, and it compiles and everything is great, it gives me the error: "command not found" for ALL of the lines in my test.txt. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: @LamaEu post another question describing your problem, including the code from `cleanLines`.